# How can I lift the type of a promise in an object?

Tags: typescript, variadic-templates

Suppose I have a function which receivese an object whose values are promise and wait all the promises to resolve, which is list below:

```
function aggregatePromiseValues<T>(promiseObject: { [key: string]: Promise<T> }) {
    /* the type is *NOT* correct */

    const promises = [];
    const result = {};
    for (let key in promiseObject) {
        const valuePromise = promiseObject[key];
        promises.push(valuePromise.then(value => result[key] = value));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => result);
}

const arg = {
    a: Promise.resolve(1),
    b: Promise.resolve('hello')
};
type resultType = Promise<{
    a: number,
    b: string
}>;

const result: resultType = aggregatePromiseValues(arg); // <--- error here
```

How can I write the the type of function `aggregatePromiseValues` so that the it can return the right type according the type of the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mapped type for argument and result:

```
function aggregatePromiseValues<T>(promiseObject: {[key in keyof T]: Promise<T[key]>}){

    const promises = [];
    const result = {} as {[key in keyof T]: T[key]};
    for (let key in promiseObject) {
        const valuePromise = promiseObject[key];
        promises.push(valuePromise.then(value => result[key] = value));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => result);
}

const arg = {
    a: Promise.resolve(1),
    b: Promise.resolve('hello')
};

const result = aggregatePromiseValues(arg);
```

type of result is inferred properly as `Promise<{ a: number; b: string; }>`, you don't have to type it explicitly.

Inside the function, you have to initialize the result with type assertion

```
    const result = {} as {[key in keyof T]: T[key]};
```

because without it, TypeScript will not allow to initialize it with empty object. If you try

```
const result: {[key in keyof T]: T[key]} = {};
```

you get an an error `Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{[key in keyof T]: T[key];}'.`

Note that you can simplify `{[key in keyof T]: T[key]}` to just `T`:

```
const result = {} as T;
```

So you don't really "lift" type out of a promise, you take normal, "unpromisified" type `T` and create new mapped type out of it with promisified properties, to use as `aggregatePromiseValues` argument type.